# Stored Procedure - General

Tags: sql, database

With a stored procedure in a database, would the following situation be true?

I have a procedure that queries a very large table, and in my query I call the stored procedure, and follow it with a `WHERE record_class = "THE ONE IM LOOKING FOR"`.

In the stored procedure I'm not limiting the records by the `record_class`, so does the `WHERE` clause do anything other than filter the results that the procedure returns?

In other words, if I wanted to speed up the results because it takes too long, would adding a parameter for the `record_class` to the procedure and selecting only those when it performs its tasks be quicker than using the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: You're correct. The stored procedure calculates its values independent of any processing that may be done after it returns. So it would be better to pass conditions into the procedure so it can do a more constrained query.

Comment: Excellent, then I know how to speed up the query!  Thank you Barmar for the confirmation!!  If you can write that as the answer I'll mark it as correct and accepted.

Comment: @Phil - Buddy exactly select only those fields which are necessary. That will take lesser time to give you results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is completely true, if you apply the condition directly in your stored procedure instead of outside it will for sure be more performant.

In the first situation, your procedure will return every rows without applying your condition (this condition is completely unknown for the procedure) and this result will then be filtered with your `WHERE` clause.

Depending on your needs, the best solution may be to define a parameter for your stored procedure so you can pass this parameter at execution and the result will be filtered. I don't know exactly what is the purpose of your procedure but by doing so, you'll keep the possibility to execute the same procedure for multiple situations (you simply need to pass the `record_class` you want to filter the result or let it `NULL` if you want the entire data).

This approach requires a little modification to your procedure (adding a parameter) and a modification of your query (adding the `WHERE` clause that filters the result if needed).

Hope this will help you.